# .NET equivalent of Java's Integer.bitCount?

Tags: java, .net, bit-manipulation, hammingweight

Is there a method similar to Java's `Integer.bitCount(int)` or `Long.bitCount(long)` anywhere in the .NET Framework?

(For those unfamiliar with these Java methods) this is also known as:

- [Hamming Weight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight)
- Population Count (often called `POPCNT` when implemented in hardware.)

Although [there](http://www.inwap.com/pdp10/hbaker/hakmem/hacks.html#item167) [are](http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?interview.11.578648.14) [plenty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697978/c-code-to-count-the-number-of-1-bits-in-an-unsigned-char) [of](http://bits.stephan-brumme.com/countBits.html) [implementations](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetParallel) [to](http://www.dotnetperls.com/bitcount) [be](http://gurmeet.net/puzzles/fast-bit-counting-routines/) found on the web, I was wondering if there was a standard library implementation.

I know this is not in `BitArray`, `UInt32` or `BitConverter`, but maybe there's a version hidden somewhere, e.g. in a crypto function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither the [`BitVector32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.bitvector32.aspx) nor the [`BitArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx) classes have such a method either so I believe that this method is indeed missing from the framework.

Personally, I think these classes aren’t really useful anyway since they miss many natural bit operations. I’m not sure what they are really intended for. As it is, their usefulness *very* limited.

Comment: Useful for efficient implementation of Hash array mapped trie: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_array_mapped_trie

Comment: @David My gripe was that the two classes have poorly designed interfaces. Of course you can use them to develop certain things but you can also use a plain bit vector (`int`) almost as well. A proper interface would make the types way more useful.

Comment: @gjsduarte you might change your mind if you meet a problem that can be easily solved with bitCount() in a job interview....(Apparently the interview himself thought this method exist in .NET)

Comment: @Kevman I think the agreement was over the fact that the .NET classes are useless, not that a bit count method would be.

Answer (score 5):

This functionality is not in .NET Framework nor .NET Standard but it is in .NET Core 3.0 and newer, thus including .NET 5.0 and newer, under the [`System.Numerics.BitOperations`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.bitoperations?view=netcore-3.0) static class, in particular the methods

- [`PopCount(System.UInt32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.bitoperations.popcount?view=netcore-3.0#System_Numerics_BitOperations_PopCount_System_UInt32_) and
- [`PopCount(System.UInt64)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.bitoperations.popcount?view=netcore-3.0#System_Numerics_BitOperations_PopCount_System_UInt64_),

both of which return `System.Int32` aka `int` in C#.

There are also other useful operations: count leading or trailing zeros, compute integer base-2 logarithm, and perform bit rotation aka circular shift.

Possibly the biggest benefit of/reason for doing this in the core libraries is that you can get hardware acceleration without linking to unmanaged code, and the class docs confirm this:

> Provides utility methods for intrinsic bit-twiddling operations. The methods use hardware intrinsics when available on the underlying platform; otherwise, they use optimized software fallbacks.

Answer (score 5):

I know it's a very old question but it might be helpful for someone like me to have at least a workaround for this:

```
public static int BitCount(int n)
{
    var count = 0;
    while (n != 0)
    {
        count++;
        n &= (n - 1); //walking through all the bits which are set to one
    }

    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These methods are based on algorithms from Hacker's Delight. You can download C code for them [here](http://www.hackersdelight.org/).

Comment: As mentioned in the question, there is no shortage of methods I could download to do the job.  The question is specifically about standard library methods.  Java has them, I don't think .NET does (but I hope to be proved wrong.)

Comment: Yeah, I know there are tons of implementations. This is as close to a library that I know of, though, given the source.